# LWJGL/OpenGL Why are there dots on the edge of my texture when i map it onto half-sphere or sphere?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

What is causing these dots (in some cases it's a line, it depends on camera angle) to appear on the edge of my texture that i map on a half-sphere or sphere?  When i map the same texture on a half-cylinder it works fine, there are no dots (line).

This is how it looks:

[image: dots on the edge]

This is how i set my texture params:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

This is how i draw my half-sphere:

```
float x, y, z;
float s, t;
double alpha1, alpha2, beta;

for(double j = 0; j < gradation; j++) {
    alpha1 = j/gradation * Math.PI;
    alpha2 = (j+1)/gradation * Math.PI;
    for(double i = 0; i <= gradation; i++) {
        beta = i/gradation * Math.PI;

        z = (float) (Math.sin(alpha1)*Math.cos(beta));
        x = (float) (Math.sin(alpha1)*Math.sin(beta));
        y = (float) Math.cos(alpha1);

        s = (float) (beta / Math.PI);
        t = (float) (alpha1 / Math.PI);

        posCoords[3*newVertexIndex] = x*radius;
        posCoords[3*newVertexIndex + 1] = y*radius;
        posCoords[3*newVertexIndex + 2] = z*radius;
        texCoords[2*newVertexIndex] = s;
        texCoords[2*newVertexIndex + 1] = t;
        indices[vertexCounter++] = newVertexIndex++;

        z = (float) (Math.sin(alpha2)*Math.cos(beta));
        x = (float) (Math.sin(alpha2)*Math.sin(beta));
        y = (float) Math.cos(alpha2);

        t = (float) (alpha2 / Math.PI);

        posCoords[3*newVertexIndex] = x*radius;
        posCoords[3*newVertexIndex + 1] = y*radius;
        posCoords[3*newVertexIndex + 2] = z*radius;
        texCoords[2*newVertexIndex] = s;
        texCoords[2*newVertexIndex + 1] = t;
        indices[vertexCounter++] = newVertexIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the source texture look like?

Comment: It's big POT texture which i load from the disk. Texture is fine because i tried it on half-cylinder and it works fine no dots or lines at the edges.

Comment: 1) Does it perhaps contain a lot of the colour white in an unmapped area? 2) Does it contain transparency?

Comment: From the image that i posted it appears that dots are white but actually they are green, and in some angles green line appears as well. When i load different texture dots/line become of different color. This is how this image looks in its entirety: [image](https://imgur.com/gallery/HaiesBT)

Comment: Have you tried to change GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE to GL_REPEAT?

Comment: I just tried GL_REPEAT, and I also tried without filtering but with no avail.

Comment: If you do a full-screen ((-1, -1) to (1, 1)) quad with the texture co-ords (0,0) to (1,1) respectively, what does it look like?

Comment: @Andrea It looks like the original source image i linked, clean without dots. Every equirectangular image I try to map ends up having those dots. When I do a full sphere it only has those dots at 0/360.

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried using mipmaps? You would just need to use GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR for your filters and call glGenerateMipmap() somewhere.

Comment: @Andrea Yes, I tried, because I felt the texture resolution was too high and because of that, there were too many details on the edge to be displayed. Downgrading texture resolution attenuated this flickering but it was still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to resolve this. Issue was that I used single `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` to draw my half-sphere, which can't be used if the shared vertices have different texture coordinates, in that case you need to use `GL_TRIANGLES`. I found out about this on this [site](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_sphere.html).